# Why does Thai have no words for "yes" or "no"?

Tags: negation, thai

There are words like /chaj/ and /mej/, but as far as I understand they are not exactly *yes* and *no*.

Comment: It can be hard to answer "why" questions like this. There are other languages with no word for "yes" or "no", and there are languages with a word for one but not the other, or that have separate words for responding to negative vs. positive questions.

Comment: In Portuguese we have words for no and yes, but I hardly ever use the word for yes in informal situations. If I were to say "yes", I wouldn't say "sim"; I'd say "é" (it is) instead. But that's not like this in other accents.

Comment: Thai: yes is chai: ใช่, no is mai: ไม่. No idea why you believe they have no yes and no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Because Thai language has other tools for expressing *polarity* ([*affirmation* and *negation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirmation_and_negation)).

---

**Polarity** is a grammatical category for expressing the speaker's assertion that a certain clause is true (positive polarity, or **affirmation**) or false (negative polarity, or **negation**).

There are numerous **linguistic tools** to encode both polarities, and each language chooses its own set of these tools.

English has much more than simple "yes" and "no". Consider [*yea* and *nay*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_and_no#The_Early_English_four-form_system), the two forms originally intended for answering questions "is it...?" (*yes* and *no* were originally used for answering inverted questions "is it **not**...?"

English also has an essential difference between *no* (negative), *no* (qualifier), and *not*.

---

As I said, Thai has different tools for expressing polarity:

First off, ไม่ `[mâj]` is a negative particle (NEG), quite similar to English *not*. Likewise in English, it is also used with verbs only:

> ผมเอา `[pʰǒm ʔaw]` — I want¹
>   ผม**ไม่**เอา `[pʰǒm mâj ʔaw]` — I don't want¹

¹ hereinafter I'm skipping polite particles for brevity; don't omit polite particles in real speech.

The positive polarity is encoded with verbs; and the negative polarity simply adds the NEG particle mentioned above:

- repeating the verb:

  > — คุณเอาไหม `[kʰun ʔaw mǎj]` — "do you want…?", literally "you want…, {INTERROG}"
  >   — เอา `[ʔaw]` — {I} want
  >   — ไม่เอา — `[mâj ʔaw]` — {I} don't want
- an indirect [flavor of "to be"](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/8939/1009) is affirmed with ใช่ `[tɕʰâj]`:

  > — ฟ้าใสไหม `[fáː sǎj mǎj]` — {the} sky {is} clear, isn't it?
  >   — ใช่ `[tɕʰâj]` — {it} is.

Comment: @Miztli, thank you for attempting to help, but formatting IPA as code make screen readers process it char-by-char and never treat it as words in a random language. While I admit that some old systems' monospace fonts lack support of combining characters, this must be a client's problem, not this site's. See also: https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15/ for the rest of your edits where I'm going to thankfully accept proofreads, but not the removal of formatting.