# What aspects of a conceptual metaphor can be compared cross-culturally?

Tags: english, cross-linguistic, pragmatics, cognitive-linguistics

I'm interested to do a cross-cultural study of a conceptual metaphor 'Love is food' between English and Thai. I would like to compare the use of this metaphor in the two languages to find similarities and differences and see what they can reflect about the two cultures. I've seen some previous works done in this fashion. But my professor want me to focus more and identify what aspects I am going to compare. I'm really confused about what aspects there are. Anyone knows the answer or have any advice? Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe that one aspect to compare is about the multiple values/meanings of the verb *"to be"*. Please take a look at [this question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/8934/1009) and my answer to it; coincidentally, it has examples in Thai! :-)

Comment: Try reading Elisabeth Piirainen; I doubt the phrase appears in her lexin of common figures of speach, but she lays out some general principles, especially a categorization of different contexts through which phrases profiliferate, one of which is to be so natural tgat the phrase can independently come up, naturally.  If your question is what's "aspect" in your context; I'm not sure phraseology was the context, so perhaps skip this book and just browse the library shelves of whatever sub-field you are working in.

Comment: bytebuster means "**Grammatical aspect**, in linguistics, a component of the conjugation of a verb, having to do with the internal temporal flow of an event", perhaps including "**Lexical aspect**, in linguistics, a distinction among different kinds of verb according to their relation to time" (from /wiki/[aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect)